# flutter app is crashing on iOS with AppBar

Tags: flutter

my app is working fine on android but for ios its crashing ,
if i comment the AppBar , its working in ios, but with app its not working.

appBar: AppBar(), // here is the problem

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(), // here is the problem
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: SafeArea(
```

main.dart code,

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    pushNotificationMessage();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<AppData>(create: (_) => AppData()),
      ],
      child: GetMaterialApp(
        title: 'ABC App',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue here is Appbar conflicting with the non safe area in your iOS device (upper notch for example), so you can fix that by one of two ways:

**First way**(*encouraged*), you can wrap your scaffold itself in the SafeArea widget instead of the body of the scaffold:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return SafeArea(
      Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(), // here is the problem
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Container(
```

**Second way,** you can remove AppBar() from the scaffold and add it inside your body widget, for example:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30), child: AppBar()),
```